# Wrong classification outputs with sklearn GMM classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm building a basic speaker recognizer with the `GMM` toolkit from `sklearn`. I have 3 classes, for each class I have a classifier. In the testing stage, the `GMM` for the speaker with the highest probability should be selected and the program should return the predicted class for each test sample. I want to vary the number of mixture components and set `n_components=4` in this example code. 
If I use 4 mixture components the output of my classifier will either be 0, 1, 2 or 3. If I use 3 mixture components, it will be 0, 1 or 2. I have the feeling that the classifier returns the predicted mixture component instead of the whole GMM. But I want it to predict the class: 1, 2 or 3.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GMM

#set path
path="path"

class_names = [1,2,3]

covs =  ['spherical', 'diag', 'tied', 'full']

training_data = {1: np.loadtxt(path+"/01_train_debug.data"), 2:  np.loadtxt(path+"/02_train_debug.data"), 3: np.loadtxt(path+"/03_train_debug.data")}

print "Training models"
models = {}
for c in class_names:
    # make a GMM for each of the classes in class_names
    models[c] = dict((covar_type,GMM(n_components=4,
                    covariance_type=covar_type, init_params='wmc',n_init=1, n_iter=20))
                   for covar_type in covs)


for cov in covs:
    for c in class_names:
            models[c][cov].fit(training_data[c])

#define test set
test01 = np.loadtxt(path+"/01_test_debug.data")
test02 = np.loadtxt(path+"/02_test_debug.data")
test03 = np.loadtxt(path+"/03_test_debug.data")

testing_data = {1: test01, 2: test02, 3: test03}

probs = {}

print "Calculating Probabilities"

for c in class_names:
    probs[c] = {}
    for cov in covs:
        probs[c][cov] = {}
        for p in class_names:
            probs[c][cov] = models[p][cov].predict(testing_data[c])


for c in class_names:
    print c
    for cov in covs:
        print "   ",cov,
        for p in class_names:
            print p, probs,
        print
```

Is my assumption from above correct or do I have a logical error in my code? 
Is there a way to solve this in sklearn? 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

<del>In your code, the first time you the keys of the `models` dict are covariance types and the second time the keys are class names.</del> I misread your code, sorry.

**Edit**: if you want the per-sample likelihood of the data under a fitted GMM models you should use the `score_samples` method. The `predict` method does not return probabilities but component assignments instead.

Also GMM by default is non supervised model. If you want to build a supervised model out of a bunch GMM models, you should probably wrap it as an estimator class that wraps them and implement the fit  / predict API to be able to estimate its accuracy via cross validation and adjust the hyper parameter values by grid search. [Pull request #2468](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2468) is implementing something like this. It it's merged in time it might get included in the next scikit-learn release (0.15 that should come out early 2014).

Comment: Thanks! I used the score_samples method initially but wasn't sure how to calculate a confusion matrix from the results. Will switch back and give it a try!

Comment: You have to take the class that matches the model with the highest score for each sample.

Comment: @ogrisel hi, I was wondering if you could have a look at a similar problem in my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414169/how-can-implement-em-gmm-in-python)
Thanks in advance.