# How can implement EM-GMM in python?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gmm

I have implemented [EM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) for [GMM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html) using this post [GMMs and Maximum Likelihood Optimization Using NumPy](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-code-gaussian-mixture-models-from-scratch-in-python-9e7975df5252) unsuccessfully as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def PDF(data, means, variances):
    return 1/(np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * variances) + eps) * np.exp(-1/2 * (np.square(data - means) / (variances + eps)))

def EM_GMM(data, k, iterations):
    weights = np.ones((k, 1)) / k # shape=(k, 1)
    means = np.random.choice(data, k)[:, np.newaxis] # shape=(k, 1)
    variances = np.random.random_sample(size=k)[:, np.newaxis] # shape=(k, 1)

    data = np.repeat(data[np.newaxis, :], k, 0) # shape=(k, n)

    for step in range(iterations):
        # Expectation step
        likelihood = PDF(data, means, np.sqrt(variances)) # shape=(k, n)

        # Maximization step
        b = likelihood * weights # shape=(k, n)
        b /= np.sum(b, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] + eps

        # updage means, variances, and weights
        means = np.sum(b * data, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] / (np.sum(b, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] + eps)
        variances = np.sum(b * np.square(data - means), axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] / (np.sum(b, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] + eps)
        weights = np.mean(b, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        
    return means, variances
```

when I run the algorithm on a 1-D time-series dataset, for k equal to 3, it returns an output like the following:

```
array([[0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    3.05053810e-003, 2.36989898e-025, 2.36989898e-025,
    1.32797395e-136, 6.91134950e-031, 5.47347807e-001,
    1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000,
    1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000,
    1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000,
    1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000,
    1.44637007e+000, 2.25849208e-064, 0.00000000e+000,
    1.61228562e-303, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 3.94387272e-242,
    1.13078186e+000, 2.53108878e-001, 5.33548114e-001,
    9.14920432e-001, 2.07015697e-013, 4.45250680e-038,
    1.43000602e+000, 1.28781615e+000, 1.44821615e+000,
    1.18186109e+000, 3.21610659e-002, 3.21610659e-002,
    3.21610659e-002, 3.21610659e-002, 3.21610659e-002,
    2.47382844e-039, 0.00000000e+000, 2.09150855e-200,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000],
   [5.93203066e-002, 1.01647068e+000, 5.99299162e-001,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 2.14690238e-010,
    2.49337135e-191, 5.10499986e-001, 9.32658804e-001,
    1.21148135e+000, 1.13315278e+000, 2.50324069e-237,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    0.00000000e+000, 1.73966953e-125, 2.53559290e-275,
    1.42960975e-065, 7.57552338e-001],
   [0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    3.05053810e-003, 2.36989898e-025, 2.36989898e-025,
    1.32797395e-136, 6.91134950e-031, 5.47347807e-001,
    1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000,
    1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000,
    1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000,
    1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000, 1.44637007e+000,
    1.44637007e+000, 2.25849208e-064, 0.00000000e+000,
    1.61228562e-303, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 3.94387272e-242,
    1.13078186e+000, 2.53108878e-001, 5.33548114e-001,
    9.14920432e-001, 2.07015697e-013, 4.45250680e-038,
    1.43000602e+000, 1.28781615e+000, 1.44821615e+000,
    1.18186109e+000, 3.21610659e-002, 3.21610659e-002,
    3.21610659e-002, 3.21610659e-002, 3.21610659e-002,
    2.47382844e-039, 0.00000000e+000, 2.09150855e-200,
    0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000]])
```

which I believe is working wrong since the outputs are two vectors which one of them represents `means` values and the other one represents `variances` values. The vague point which made me doubtful about implementation is it returns back `0.00000000e+000` for most of the outputs as it can be seen and it doesn't need really to visualize these outputs. BTW the input data are **time-series** data. I have checked everything and traced multiple times but no bug shows up.

Here are my input data:

```
[25.31      , 24.31      , 24.12      , 43.46      , 41.48666667,
   41.48666667, 37.54      , 41.175     , 44.81      , 44.44571429,
   44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429,
   44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429,
   44.44571429, 44.44571429, 39.71      , 26.69      , 34.15      ,
   24.94      , 24.75      , 24.56      , 24.38      , 35.25      ,
   44.62      , 44.94      , 44.815     , 44.69      , 42.31      ,
   40.81      , 44.38      , 44.56      , 44.44      , 44.25      ,
   43.66666667, 43.66666667, 43.66666667, 43.66666667, 43.66666667,
   40.75      , 32.31      , 36.08      , 30.135     , 24.19      ]
```

I was wondering if there is an elegant way to implement it via `numpy` or `SciKit-learn`. Any helps will be appreciated.

**Update**
Following is current output and expected output:
[image: img]

Comment: Could you share why you think it is wrong? Visualizing might help, but even without, there seems to be some explanation missing

Comment: @dia The outputs are two vectors which one of them represents `means` values and the other one represents `variances` values. The vague point which made me doubtful about implementation is it returns back `0.00000000e+000` for most of the outputs as it can be seen and it doesn't need really to visualize these outputs. BTW the input data are **time-series** data.

Comment: Which can be visualized. I have a link post on the mean. why dont you refer to it.

Comment: @dia you mean this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298542/scikit-learn-gmm-issue-with-return-from-means-attribute) or [GMM/EM on time series cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229504/gmm-em-on-time-series-cluster?). Do you have any offer and solution to achieve the right results in output or explanation about my current results?

Comment: I used to get these comments in the beginning that I found unnice, but now I seem to get them. Allow me to rephrase  kindly. You have to either make it easy for others to understand and address your issue, otherwise solve it on your own.

Comment: @dia kindly I rephrased by integrating details explanation into the post to make it clear. Besides bounty is included!

Comment: @Mario using `k=3` I am getting `(3,1)` shaped `means` and `variances`. Also the algorithm is running with no issue. Only critical point I see is initialization of the mean, with these skewed data it is likely to have 2 overlapping gaussians out of 3. Using `k=2` is a better fit.
I am not sure what your output is, and it looks very weird. I can elaborate more of what I am getting in an answer if needed

Comment: @FBruzzesi thanks for your input. I have updated the post by including the Visualizing to have a better understanding of right fit and distributions. I'll be happy if you have further input or elaboration in this regard. FYI I found another way to implement and it resulted in the bottom figure which your approach can confirm that! but I'm unsure still.

Comment: @Mario I hope my answer helps you understanding mean initialization, yet the resulting variances doesn't feel right. I will look into it when I will have some spare time. In particular I would expect the 35-meaned cluster to have larger variance than the resulting one, possibly similar to the one in your expected output

Comment: @FBruzzesi I'm very appreciated your answer and your input about `mean` initialization and feel free if you want to update it regarding `variance` because I see eye to eye with you. Kindly I also connect with you in Linkedin due to further research investigation we can cooperate since we have much in common. Let me know if you are interested in involving in paper and articles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the critical point that I see is the `means` initialization. Following the default implementation of [sklearn Gaussian Mixture](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html), instead of random initialization, I switched to KMeans.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')

eps=1e-8 

def PDF(data, means, variances):
    return 1/(np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * variances) + eps) * np.exp(-1/2 * (np.square(data - means) / (variances + eps)))

def EM_GMM(data, k=3, iterations=100, init_strategy='kmeans'):
    weights = np.ones((k, 1)) / k # shape=(k, 1)
    
    if init_strategy=='kmeans':
        from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
        
        km = KMeans(k).fit(data[:, None])
        means = km.cluster_centers_ # shape=(k, 1)
        
    else: # init_strategy=='random'
        means = np.random.choice(data, k)[:, np.newaxis] # shape=(k, 1)
    
    variances = np.random.random_sample(size=k)[:, np.newaxis] # shape=(k, 1)

    data = np.repeat(data[np.newaxis, :], k, 0) # shape=(k, n)

    for step in range(iterations):
        # Expectation step
        likelihood = PDF(data, means, np.sqrt(variances)) # shape=(k, n)

        # Maximization step
        b = likelihood * weights # shape=(k, n)
        b /= np.sum(b, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] + eps

        # updage means, variances, and weights
        means = np.sum(b * data, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] / (np.sum(b, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] + eps)
        variances = np.sum(b * np.square(data - means), axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] / (np.sum(b, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] + eps)
        weights = np.mean(b, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        
    return means, variances
```

This seems to yield the desired output much more consistently:

```py
s = np.array([25.31      , 24.31      , 24.12      , 43.46      , 41.48666667,
              41.48666667, 37.54      , 41.175     , 44.81      , 44.44571429,
              44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429,
              44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429,
              44.44571429, 44.44571429, 39.71      , 26.69      , 34.15      ,
              24.94      , 24.75      , 24.56      , 24.38      , 35.25      ,
              44.62      , 44.94      , 44.815     , 44.69      , 42.31      ,
              40.81      , 44.38      , 44.56      , 44.44      , 44.25      ,
              43.66666667, 43.66666667, 43.66666667, 43.66666667, 43.66666667,
              40.75      , 32.31      , 36.08      , 30.135     , 24.19      ])
k=3
n_iter=100

means, variances = EM_GMM(s, k, n_iter)
print(means,variances)
[[44.42596231]
 [24.509301  ]
 [35.4137508 ]] 
[[0.07568723]
 [0.10583743]
 [0.52125856]]

# Plotting the results
colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow']
bins = np.linspace(np.min(s)-2, np.max(s)+2, 100)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('pdf')

sns.scatterplot(s, [0.05] * len(s), color='navy', s=40, marker=2, label='Series data')

for i, (m, v) in enumerate(zip(means, variances)):
    sns.lineplot(bins, PDF(bins, m, v), color=colors[i], label=f'Cluster {i+1}')

plt.legend()
plt.plot()
```

[image: EM_result]

Finally we can see that the purely random initialization generates different results; let's see the resulting `means`:

```py
for _ in range(5):
    print(EM_GMM(s, k, n_iter, init_strategy='random')[0], '\n')

[[44.42596231]
 [44.42596231]
 [44.42596231]]

[[44.42596231]
 [24.509301  ]
 [30.1349997 ]]

[[44.42596231]
 [35.4137508 ]
 [44.42596231]]

[[44.42596231]
 [30.1349997 ]
 [44.42596231]]

[[44.42596231]
 [44.42596231]
 [44.42596231]]
```

One can see how different these results are, in some cases the resulting means is constant, meaning that inizalization chose 3 similar values and didn't change much while iterating. Adding some print statements inside the `EM_GMM` will clarify that.

Comment: I found a few problems with this implementation. I am putting it below.

Comment: Thanks for the implementation. There is a strong mistake... This doesn't work. In this line `b /= np.sum(b, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] + eps` you should use `axis=0`

Comment: @ivallesp I am aware of the wrong solution, I cannot delete it because bounty has been given, I don't have time to review it properly, I flagged this issue to moderators but nothing has been done. I think Mario should accept the answer from koshy george.

Answer (score 5):

```
# Expectation step
likelihood = PDF(data, means, np.sqrt(variances))
```

- Why are we passing `sqrt` of `variances`? The pdf function accept variances. So this should be `PDF(data, means, variances)`.

Another problem,

```
# Maximization step
b = likelihood * weights # shape=(k, n)
b /= np.sum(b, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] + eps
```

- The second line above should be `b /= np.sum(b, axis=0)[:, np.newaxis] + eps`

Also in the initialization of `variances`,

```
variances = np.random.random_sample(size=k)[:, np.newaxis] # shape=(k, 1)
```

- Why are we random initializing variances? We have the `data` and `means`, why not compute the current estimated variances as in `vars = np.expand_dims(np.mean(np.square(data - means), axis=1), -1)` ?

With these changes, here is my implementation,

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')

eps=1e-8


def pdf(data, means, vars):
    denom = np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * vars) + eps
    numer = np.exp(-0.5 * np.square(data - means) / (vars + eps))
    return numer /denom


def em_gmm(data, k, n_iter, init_strategy='k_means'):
    weights = np.ones((k, 1), dtype=np.float32) / k
    if init_strategy == 'k_means':
        from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
        km = KMeans(k).fit(data[:, None])
        means = km.cluster_centers_
    else:
        means = np.random.choice(data, k)[:, np.newaxis]
    data = np.repeat(data[np.newaxis, :], k, 0)
    vars = np.expand_dims(np.mean(np.square(data - means), axis=1), -1)
    for step in range(n_iter):
        p = pdf(data, means, vars)
        b = p * weights
        denom = np.expand_dims(np.sum(b, axis=0), 0) + eps
        b = b / denom
        means_n = np.sum(b * data, axis=1)
        means_d = np.sum(b, axis=1) + eps
        means = np.expand_dims(means_n / means_d, -1)
        vars = np.sum(b * np.square(data - means), axis=1) / means_d
        vars = np.expand_dims(vars, -1)
        weights = np.expand_dims(np.mean(b, axis=1), -1)

    return means, vars


def main():
    s = np.array([25.31, 24.31, 24.12, 43.46, 41.48666667,
                  41.48666667, 37.54, 41.175, 44.81, 44.44571429,
                  44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429,
                  44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429, 44.44571429,
                  44.44571429, 44.44571429, 39.71, 26.69, 34.15,
                  24.94, 24.75, 24.56, 24.38, 35.25,
                  44.62, 44.94, 44.815, 44.69, 42.31,
                  40.81, 44.38, 44.56, 44.44, 44.25,
                  43.66666667, 43.66666667, 43.66666667, 43.66666667, 43.66666667,
                  40.75, 32.31, 36.08, 30.135, 24.19])
    k = 3
    n_iter = 100

    means, vars = em_gmm(s, k, n_iter)
    y = 0
    colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow']
    bins = np.linspace(np.min(s) - 2, np.max(s) + 2, 100)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    plt.xlabel('$x$')
    plt.ylabel('pdf')
    sns.scatterplot(s, [0.0] * len(s), color='navy', s=40, marker=2, label='Series data')
    for i, (m, v) in enumerate(zip(means, vars)):
        sns.lineplot(bins, pdf(bins, m, v), color=colors[i], label=f'Cluster {i + 1}')
    plt.legend()
    plt.plot()

    plt.show()
    pass
```

And here is my result.
[image: pdf plots of clusters]

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was wondering why the summit of side Gaussian curves are so [sharp](https://i.imgur.com/WWPRHp7.png) and why PDF exceeds 1.0?

Comment: PDF is the density function. Its value can exceed 1.0. (e.g dirac-delta pdf) But the area under the curve (total probability) has to be 1.0

Comment: If you find my answers acceptable, please upvote my answer.

Comment: ` I was wondering why the summit of side Gaussian curves are so sharp `? For drawing the gaussian curve we sample the interval and do a line-plot of vaues without any smoothing. Hence the sharpness

Comment: I see your point of view! Thanks again for your insightful input.

Comment: I believe this should be accepted in place of my faulty answer